# DHCP and DNS on none AD 2003 Server PTR is updating but no A records

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, dhcp, a-record, ptr-record

I have a strange issue, I have a DHCP and DNS server running in a non AD environment, on Windows 2003 server. I setup DHCP to update DNS A and PTR records even if the client doesnt request it, but I only see PTR records updated, the A records are not created at all. The domain is "local" forward zone is called "local" and in the option 15 set to "local" (actual name) the PTR records are created with the right name (example: win64_ent.local), What am I missing here ?

Comment: If you configure the client's networking settings correctly, and then you execute an ipconfig /registerdns from said client, does the A record get created?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the properties of the *local* DNS zone are set to allow Dynamic Updates. To check/set this right click on the zone in the DNS MMC and select properties. The Dynamic Updates option is on the General Tab.

Comment: I do have that enabled still same thing

Comment: Have you checked that the security permissions of the local zone is the same as the PTR zone?